# Global sections of ample line bundles over (rational) elliptic fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-surfaces, ample-bundles

Let $S$ be a smooth, complex elliptic fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $L$ be an ample invertible sheaf on $S$. I am looking for criterion under which $L$ has a non-trivial global section. Any idea/reference will be most welcome.